# Handling CORS in communication through web-sockets

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io, cors

I'm developing a client and server app, that communicate over web-sockets and found that handling CORS only on the web-socket doesn't raise any additional CORS issues, without handling CORS on the server side itself.

Before solving the issue the error on the client side was:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOOM0wp' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the response object, that appears only if I handle CORS on the server side.

But, on the client side I get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NOONjI6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I guess this is a pretty simple issue, still an explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cors` configuration.

Refer to [Handling CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/).

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var app = express()
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*" // add your own origin, or '*' for any origins allow.
  }
})
```